# Using Tether Javascript Library causing exception

Tags: javascript, html, css, tether

I am working on a new website and I want to include a footer at the bottom of a container div.

I found a javascript library called Tether (http://github.hubspot.com/tether/) but I am having a problem with the implementation.

Below is my HTML code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bug Reporting</title>
        <link href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="includes/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="includes/tether/tether.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                new Tether({
                    element: '.footer',
                    target: '.container',
                    attachment: 'top left',
                    targetAttachment: 'bottom left'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header>
                This is the body
            </header>

            <div id="content">
                This is the content<br />
            </div>

            <div class="footer1">
                This is the footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is my StyleSheet

```
html, body
{
    font-family: arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}

.container
{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    width: 100%;
}

#content
{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 1024px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.footer1
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
```

The problem is when I load the page I get an exception within the tether library

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tether's [options](http://github.hubspot.com/tether/#options) define `element` and `target` as being a DOM or jQuery **element** (in quite a loose sense of the word), not a string.

You need to pass a jQuery object to Tether, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    new Tether({
        element: $('.footer'),
        target: $('.container'),
        attachment: 'top left',
        targetAttachment: 'bottom left'
    });
});
```

Also make sure the elements are on the page when you initialise your Tether instance.

Comment: Thanks, documentation didn't mention that (not that I noticed anyway), thanks for the help

Comment: Not a problem. I was confused by the docs as well. They're not worded particularly clearly, and they're below all the examples, too

Comment: As of Dec 30, Tether does accept a selector string (e.g. http://github.hubspot.com/tether/examples/simple/).  Just updated the doc, thanks for the feedback.